# How do I make an adjacency matrix in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, graph, vertex

So here's the code I have right now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                System.out.print(B[i][j] + ": ");
                if (i < 2){
                    temp2 = B[i+1][j];
                    System.out.print(temp2 + "-");
                }

                if (j < 2){
                    temp2 = B[i][j+1];
                    System.out.print(temp2 + "-");
                }

                if (i > 0){
                    temp2 = B[i-1][j];
                    System.out.print(temp2 + "-");
                }
                if (j > 0){
                    temp2 = B[i][j-1];
                    System.out.print(temp2 + "-");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }
```

What it's doing right now is printing out a list which looks like this:

```
1: 4-0
0: 2-3-1
3: 6-0
4: 7-2-1
2: 5-6-0-4
6: 8-3-2
7: 5-4
5: 8-2-7
8: 6-5
```

This list is the adjacent vertices for this graph

```
1 0 3  
4 2 6
7 5 8
```

I have checked and it does print out the correct adjacent vertices for each value in this 2d array. So I'm wondering how you would turn this into an adjacency matrix. I know I have to first create a 2d array of size 9x9 but I'm having trouble actually putting the values in the correct places in the array. So when I find the adjacent vertex, how could I put that value into an adjacency matrix? I could also try to put these into a linked list because that would take up less space but I think a matrix would be easier.

Comment: Since the first line shows that 1 is connected to 4 and to 0, isn't it as simple as `m[1][4] = 1; m[4][1] = 1; m[1][0] = 1; m[0][1] = 1;`?

Comment: When your code output `1: 4-0`, that wasn't hard-coded was it? No, it was from variables, producing the number `1`, `4`, and `0`. So when I (as an example) showed that `1: 4-0` would result in `m[1][4] = 1; m[4][1] = 1; m[1][0] = 1; m[0][1] = 1;`, both would be using those variables. I didn't intend to imply that you'd write those 4 assignments directly, just that through code those 4 assignments would be made.

Comment: nvm I just figured it out. I had to make a temp1 variable and set it to B[i][j].

Answer (score 0):

If you call your 9x9 adjacency matrix M, and you figure out that node 0 is adjacent to 2, 3 and 1, you set

```
M[0][2]=1
M[0][3]=1
M[0][1]=1
```

And because the adjacency matrix is symmetrical:

```
M[2][0]=1
M[3][0]=1
M[1][0]=1
```

The indices tell you which nodes you are referring to, and the value is 1 if the nodes are adjacent and 0 otherwise.
This does sound like a homework assignment you should figure out yourself.